# accessing returned data from a states resolve function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am using an AngularJS module `ui-router` and using the `resolve` property to fetch the id of an item.

In a separate file I have the component, `patent` for a state `patents.patent`, which has the function that returns the `id`. I need to access the returned `id` from the controller so I can then gather the correct data related to the selected item.

How do I access the `resolve` function returned value from the controller?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'chart.js']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('patents', {
        url: '/patents',
        component: 'patents',
        resolve: {
            patents: function(patentsService) {
                return patentsService.fetchAllPatents();
            },
            graphs: function(patentsService) {
                return  patentsService.fetchGraphData();
            }

        }      
    })
    .state('patents.patent', {
        url: '/{patentId}',
        component: 'patent',
        resolve: {
            patent: function(patents, $stateParams) {
                return patents.find(function(patent){ 
                    return patent.id == $stateParams.patentId;
                })
            },
            graph: function(graphs, $stateParams) {
                return graphs.dataset.find(function(graph){
                    return graph.id == $stateParams.patentId; //NEED THIS VALUE
                })
            }
        }
    })

}]);
```

---

```
angular.module('myApp').component('patent', {
    bindings: { 
        patent: '=' ,
    },
    templateUrl: '../templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm',
    controller: function() {
        var vm = this;

        //WHERE I NEED TO ACCESS THE RETURNED VALUE

    }
});
```

Comment: You can inject the resolves into your controller function like controller: function(patents,graphs)

Comment: That's what I thought but it comes up with error `Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider`

Comment: You can use a directive instead of a component, the structure looks the same, but Idk what you are trying to achieve with component

Comment: Advised by other developers to do so, and by Angular's documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: You can use  a route controller which will act as a glue between the resolve and the Component. Its job is to inject all the 'resolves' and them on the scope, so that the template can access them.For more reference http://dontpanic.42.nl/2016/07/using-ui-router-as-component-router.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your resolved data you simply define them as bindings to your controller. Like you've already done with `patent`. Then you access them through your `vm` variable (or this).

```
angular.module('myApp').component('patent', {
    bindings: { 
        patent: '<' ,
        graph: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: '../templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm',
    controller: function() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.$onChanges = function(changeObj){
            if(changeObj.patent){
                console.log('I am your patent', vm.patent);
            }
            if(changeObj.patent){
                console.log('I am your graph', vm.graph);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As @rrd suggests, you should guard your controllers against minification, but not only that, you should also guard your resolve functions from minification.

Like so:

```
resolve: {
    patents: ['patentsService', function(patentsService) {
        return patentsService.fetchAllPatents();
    }],
    graphs: ['patentsService', function(patentsService) {
        return  patentsService.fetchGraphData();
    }]
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation and example, but the first approach returns undefined, and the second one returns the same error message as stated above. I have been reading what Vivz posted, http://dontpanic.42.nl/2016/07/using-ui-router-as-component-router.html . Seem to be making progress but an error is being returned

Comment: Try adding a `console.log()` inside your resolve function to check whether they actually return any value - or if they're even called. The problem doesn't seem to be the controllers per se.

Comment: Yeah done that. Returns the correct data for both the patent and graph resolves

Comment: Hmm, alright. Nothing seems wrong in the code you've shared so far, so perhaps the error originates from elsewhere. Could you share the entire error message in your question?

Comment: Sure. The message returned by taking your second approach you recommended comes back with https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=patentProvider%20%3C-%20patent

Comment: Nice catch on the resolve guarding too @NikolajDamLarsen

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen thank you so much!!! Works like a trooper. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As Vivz pointed out, injection into the controller should work, but you need to ensure to guard against minification issues:

```
angular.module('myApp').component('patent', {
  bindings: { 
    patent: '=' ,
  },
  templateUrl: '../templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm',
  controller: ['graph', function(graph) {
    var vm = this;

    //WHERE I NEED TO ACCESS THE RETURNED VALUE

  }]
});
```

Comment: I understand safe guarding against minimisation issues, but still the error `Error: $injector:unprUnknown Provider` shows :/